# Read chunk from Gridfs and convert to Buffer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, buffer, gridfs

I got a question about buffer. Here is my code:

```
var Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var gfs = Grid(db, mongodb);
var deferred = Q.defer();
var image_buf = new Buffer('buffer');
var readableStream = gfs.createReadStream(name);

readableStream.on('data',function(chunk){  
    console.log(chunk);
    image_buf = Buffer.concat([image_buf, chunk]);
    console.log(image_buf)//differ from the chunk above
});
readableStream.on('end',function(){
    db.close();
    deferred.resolve(image_buf);
})
return deferred.promise;
```

What I'm doing is to read an image from MongoDB and put it in the gridfs-stream. I really want to retrieve all chunks in the stream and pass them to another variable so that I can reuse these chunks to draw an image in another API. Therefore I use image_buf and Buffer to perform the task. However, I get a completely different buffer string. As you can see in the above code, I consoled the chunk and the image_buf I got, but they are totally different. Can anyone tell me the reason for this and how can I correctly collect all chunks? Thanks a lot!!!

UPDATE: OK, so I figured it out now: I will append my code below for anyone who is struggling with the same problem as mine:

```
    readableStream.on('data',function(chunk){ 
        console.log("writing!!!");
        if (!image_buf)
            image_buf = chunk;
        else image_buf = Buffer.concat([image_buf, chunk]);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out. Though "!image_buf" doesn't work if you initialize the buffer with 'buffer' like you did in the first piece of code, before the update. It should be initialize with a blank string :)

Answer (score 5):

The update provided by question poster does not work . So i am going to provide answer of my own. Instead of using `new Buffer('buffer')` it is better to use an simple array and push chunks into it and use `Buffer.concat(bufferArray)` at the end to get buffer of stream like this:

```
var readableStream = gfs.createReadStream(name);
var bufferArray = [];
readableStream.on('data',function(chunk){  
    bufferArray.push(chunk);
});
readableStream.on('end',function(){
    var buffer = Buffer.concat(bufferArray);
    deferred.resolve(buffer);
})
```